# How to load test Alexa's skill

Tags: testing, automated-tests, load-testing, alexa-skills-kit

I have alexa skill and I want to test a lot of users connection, I want to use JMeter, bit I don't sure is it required to tests skills. How do you do load testing for Alexas skills and is it required?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you do load testing for Alexas skills?

You can do load testing for your skill's backend `HTTPS` endpoint which generates the responses for your skill. From your tool hit the endpoint with different varieties of requests, various `sessionAttributes` values  and `intents` according to your skills use case and testing configuration/load. If the skill supports account linking, test with that scenario also.

> is it required?

In order get your skill certified/published, **No**.